# How to click button or submit form or click url or click image on C# 4.0 WPF webbrowser application

Tags: c#, wpf, button, click, browser

I am using C# 4.0 WPF application webbrowser element. What i want is after page load completed i want to click a particular link or submit a particular form or click a particular image or click a particular button.

This click event should be same as mouse click event because some of them executing javascripts on click or do other stuff.

How can i do those 4 event ?

Also how do i bind a function to the loadcompleted event. I mean a function will be executed when page load completed ?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have access to change the web page source?

Comment: yes i can change web page source . i don't own the web page but my desktop application can change it while loading.

Comment: You should use `jQuery.Ready()` event handler http://api.jquery.com/ready/ to trigger specific events to happen after loaded.

Comment: yes it was also on my mind. do you know what is the proper way of injecting jquery to the source code.

Comment: take a look at jquerify http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/04/better-stronger-safer-jquerify-bookmarklet

Comment: my question is not about jquery. my question is how do i insert jquery to the loaded page on webbrowser.

Answer (score 0):

In the LoadCompleted event do the following:

```
    private void WebBrowser_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        var doc = (WebBrowser.Document as HTMLDocument);

        if (doc != null)
        {
            var element = doc.getElementById("button id"); //Id of the input element
            if (element != null)
            { 
                element.click();
            }

        }


    }
```

You will need to add a reference to Microsoft.mshtml (it is under assemblies -> extensions).